# Android -> PHP подключение

Tags: php, android

```
    package inc.daniilsud.database2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Formatter;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class SelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);
        final Button btnQuery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnQuery);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final EditText etParameter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btnQuery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isOnline()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Нет соединения с интернетом!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                RegConnection conn = new RegConnection();
                conn.execute(etParameter.getText().toString(), Integer.toString(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
            }
        });
    }


    private class RegConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://r-rp.su/php/android.php");
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("spinneritem", params[1]);
                //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("value", params[0]);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("spinneritem", params[1]);
                data.put("value", params[0]);
                // byte[] data = ("spinneritem="+params[1]+"&value="+params[0]).getBytes();
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
               // BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
                bos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                os.close();
                urlConnection.connect();

                //urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
    public boolean isOnline() {
        String cs = Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(cs);
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит мой текущий код. Суть в том, что при отладке не происходит ошибок, а PHP файл должен принимать корректно.

```
<?php
try {
file_put_contents('1',"1");
$unput_json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$spinneritem = $input_json['sninneritem'];
$value = $input_json['value'];
echo 1;
$query = "";
file_put_contents('android.txt', $spinneritem." - item ".$value." - value\n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);

switch($spinneritem)
{
    case 0:
        $query = "SELECT FLIGHTS.NUM, FLIGHTS.START_TIME, FLIGHTS.AIRPORT_TARGET FROM FLIGHTS
                            INNER JOIN startings ON startings.flight_num=flights.num
                            INNER JOIN PLANES ON startings.plane_code=PLANES.PLANE_CODE
                            WHERE PLANES.TYPE=?";

        break;
}

try {
    $dbh = new PDO();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($value);
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $ret = json_encode($res);
    file_put_contents('android.txt', $ret." - returned value \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
    echo $res;


    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    file_put_contents('android.txt', $e->getMessage()." - exception \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
    die();
}
}
catch(Exception $e) {
     file_put_contents('android.txt', $e->getMessage()." - exception \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
}

?>
```

Вопрос следующий - по идее PHP интерпретируемый язык, поэтому он должен выполнить создание файлов (все file_put_contents нужны для проверки). Не создается ничего. Может ли быть такое, что при создании буфера и вброса его в поток php не обрабатывается как обычно и срабатывает как "API" только по БД/echo части? Иначе не знаю как объяснить ошибку

Comment: Ошибки какие? Если их нет, то включите отображение ошибок PHP,  а на стороне клиента посмотрите, что возвращает запрос

Comment: @rjhdby включил лог ошибок пхп, ничего нет. Опять же не исполняется даже первая строка. По дебагу приложения все подключения и буферы создаются и идёт нормальное завершение

Comment: Запустите этот файл отдельно в PHP отладчике, аероятно что-то не так с синтаксисом.

Comment: А права на запись то есть?

Comment: @rjhdby вы имеете в виду права на запись file_put_contents? Если да, то просто запустив скрипт r-rp.su/php/android.php он сработает и создастся файл и пустая запись в android.txt.

Comment: Тогда смотрите, что вам `urlConnection` возвращает. И тело и заголовки.